# The "delete" comment link not working in SO Android app

Tags: discussion, bug, android-app, deleted-comments

When I was reviewing one of my answers I noticed I had one unnecessary comment among the others, so I tried to deleted it, but here is the issue:

Tapping the **`delete`** link doesn't do anything.

Here is a **Screenshot**:

[image: SO_delete_link]

### **APP Info:**

**Name:** SoClient

**Filename:** com.sudosaints.stackoverflow

**Version:** 1.0

Is this a bug?

Comment: Just tried to tap the delete link and it deleted the comment for me ...

Comment: well I tried several times, even before posting this question, and as I said, no response when tapping the `delete`link.

Comment: Just deleted my comment on Nexus 5, Lollipop 5.1, SE app 1.0.63. Now, if you could add the specs you're using, this would become a better bug report. Edit: btw, by "delete" link, did you mean trash icon on menu bar? Becausr I didn't see any link inside the app (and I have been using it for long time)

Comment: question updated. we are talking about different Apps I'm guessing.

Comment: After (finally) connecting my phone to the internet and searching on the name of the app you give, **this is a third party app** and the bug you've encountered is not one that SE can fix. The app was created by SudoSaints, and even says on the app page that this is _not_ the official application. You should report this to the app developer, not to SE.

Comment: @Kendra you're right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SoClient](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sudosaints.stackoverflow) is not the official Stack Exchange app. You'll need to contact the developer of that app to report this bug.

The Google Play page lists `contact@sudosaints.com` and http://sudosaints.com.

FYI: [Official Stack Exchange app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin)